# Hi there, I am trying to find the max consecutive ones but python throws an error

Tags: python

I have tried to implement this code but python just blocks me by saying that ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

```
def max_running(n):
   # Initialize result
   c = 0
   # Count the number of iterations to
   # reach x = 0.
   while (n!=0):
      # This operation reduces length
      # of every sequence of 1s by one.
      n = (n & (n << 1))
      c=c+1
   return c
# Driver code
n = sample_converted#array converted into binary file
print("Maximum Length of 1's ::>",max_running(n))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of `sample_converted` (one that we can copy and paste to create an object in Python)?

Comment: First I load the file sample like this which is filled with 'H' and 'T'. Then I morph into sample converted which will be just 0 and 1. Here the example:

import numpy as np
sample = np.load("sample_1.npy")#search for how to load a ".npy" file

#how it looks like: ['H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'T' 'T' 'H' 'T' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'T' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' 'H' then:

sample_converted = np.where(sample == 'H', 0, 1)

#how it looks like [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

Thanks in advance

print(sample)

Comment: Do you need to convert to 0s and 1s, or do you only care about getting the maximum consecutive number of tails?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
def max_running(n):
   # Initialize result
   c = 0
   # Count the number of iterations to
   # reach x = 0.
   while any(i for i in n):
      # This operation reduces length
      # of every sequence of 1s by one.
      n = (n & (n << 1))
      c=c+1
   return c
# Driver code
n = sample_converted#array converted into binary fild1
print("Maximum Length of 1's ::>",max_running(n))
```

Comment: could you clarify why should be all(i for i in n)?

Comment: changed to ```any```